# How heavy can my fireplace be?

Tags: floor

Hello: I am a diy and am relocating a gas fireplace. It backs on an outside wall with one floor joist parallel to the wall under the fireplace. The joist is 2x10 x25ft. Beneath is a wall on an concrete basement floor that crosses at 18ft, 2x4 with no header but shimmed at the top( its a finished basement so it’s hard to see what is what) The base of the fireplace is centred on the 25ft span and is 20 x 77 inches. A lot of the construction is fastened to the wall with 4 inch screws to the 12ft peak. So far it weighs about 700lbs but I have yet to apply a stacked stone floor  to ceiling finish. How much further in weight can I go? Should I build a concrete footing beneath in the basement?

Comment: Our local contractor puts in some kind of concrete foundation if he is putting in a stone fireplace instead of an inset type  fireplace. Pretty easy here because there are no basements in the area.

Comment: Thx blacksmith37  I’m thinking better be safe than sorry!

Comment: Just to be sure, is the stacked stone natural stone that will be 4-5" thick or a veneer stone set with thinset to backer board fastened to the studs/framing?

Comment: The Code allows a maximum axial load on an isolated footing (as opposed to a continuous footing) of 9,000 lbs. before it needs to be “designed”. (See ICC R403.1.2.1)

Comment: Is it going to be a masonry fireplace with stone veneer?

Comment: It’s a stone veneer on concrete backer board with wood construction . It already has a 400lbs flagstone base and a 180lbs barn beam mantle.

Comment: @LeeSam It seems like the wall will carry the stone veneer load back to the footing since it is in essence carried by the framing and not directly bearing on the floor joists? Might need to use plywood under the backer board, which will allow 1/4' backer board to be used? Then a sketch from the OP would be helpful.

Comment: trying to figure out how to send a picture. Old guy problem! 1/2 inch cement board in place now without plywood backing, did I make another error?

Comment: Depends on how the walls are configured that surround the firebox...

Comment: Thx for your help blacksmith37, Lee Sam and Jack. I have solved the cement board issue from another local source, no error, and the weight issue will be solved with a single footing and a tee as overkill. My son in law is dealing with a similar issue in new construction and a 14000lbs full stone fireplace. Thx again.